# why do we use setTimout function if AJAX is asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have been using jquery libraries for implementing AJAX. it was ok and I am comfortable with that. However, I started reading some ajax book and found the following code.

```
// stores the reference to the XMLHttpRequest object
var xmlHttp = createXmlHttpRequestObject();
// retrieves the XMLHttpRequest object
function createXmlHttpRequestObject()
{
    // will store the reference to the XMLHttpRequest object
    var xmlHttp;
    // if running Internet Explorer
    if(window.ActiveXObject)
    {
        try
        {
        xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch (e)
        {
        xmlHttp = false;
        }
    }// if running Mozilla or other browsers
    else
    {
        try
        {
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        catch (e)
        {
        xmlHttp = false;
        }
    }
    // return the created object or display an error message
    if (!xmlHttp)
    alert("Error creating the XMLHttpRequest object.");
    else
    return xmlHttp;
}

// make asynchronous HTTP request using the XMLHttpRequest object
function process()
{
    // proceed only if the xmlHttp object isn't busy
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 || xmlHttp.readyState == 0)
    {
        // retrieve the name typed by the user on the form
        name = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("myName").value);
        // execute the quickstart.php page from the server
        xmlHttp.open("GET", "quickstart.php?name=" + name, true);
        // define the method to handle server responses
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse;
        // make the server request
        xmlHttp.send(null);
    }
    else
    // if the connection is busy, try again after one second
    setTimeout('process()', 1000);
}


//executed automatically when a message is received from the server
function handleServerResponse()
{
    // move forward only if the transaction has completed
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4)
    {
        // status of 200 indicates the transaction completed successfully
        if (xmlHttp.status == 200)
        {
        // extract the XML retrieved from the server
        xmlResponse = xmlHttp.responseXML;
        // obtain the document element (the root element) of the XML structure
        xmlDocumentElement = xmlResponse.documentElement;
        // get the text message, which is in the first child of
        // the the document element
        helloMessage = xmlDocumentElement.firstChild.data;
        // update the client display using the data received from the server
        document.getElementById("divMessage").innerHTML =
        '<i>' + helloMessage + '</i>';
        // restart sequence
        setTimeout('process()', 1000);
        }
        // a HTTP status different than 200 signals an error
        else
        {
        alert("There was a problem accessing the server: " + xmlHttp.statusText);
        }
    }
}
```

Here my question is why do we use `setTimeout('process()', 1000);` in handleServerResponse() function? Can't we do this without  setTimeout('process()', 1000);?

Comment: If you're using jQuery, as you say you are, you can get rid of all that code and just use jQuery's simple AJAX functions: http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

Comment: The problem here is that you're only using a single `XMLHttpRequest` object (`xmlHttp`) and you'd overwrite the request if you set it to other values.

Comment: What book is this from?

Comment: If this is from an actual book, I would consider this rather low quality code, not least the use of the string form of `setTimeout`.

Comment: As the comment says, it's used to `// restart sequence`

Comment: guys he's just asking a question about why in the book example there's the setTimeout not which is better to use.... and for answering your question i don't really know to me it seems like a loop that keep requesting every second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the given example , the book has call the process() function on the body onload event.
When I change the code to onload-> to onkeyup  `<input type="text" id="myName" onkeyup="process()"/>` I could remove the code `//setTimeout('process()', 1000);`

Answer (score 1):

For me, it looks like some kind of *constant polling*. It's reusing the AJAX request over and over every second, and when the previous request is still active, it waits another second to send it again. So it's not just *create an AJAX request and deal with the response*.

Using that code, the page would be updating constantly with the information retrieved from the server. Whenever server response has changed, page will as well but not in real time (only when next request finishes). It's similar to [Periodic Refresh](http://ajaxpatterns.org/Periodic_Refresh).

As an evolution, you can have Long Polling in which you spawn an AJAX request and then wait until server responds. If any info is there in the server for you, you'll receive the response immediately. If, while you are waiting for response, anything comes to the server for you, you will receive it. If your request times out, server will respond with an empty body. Then, your client will spawn another AJAX request. You can get some more info [from the Wikipedia](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling). Extra link: [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29#Ajax_with_long_polling).